# Why data in Lazy Loading C# is loaded before I need it?

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

In one website I read:

> Lady loading is the concept of delaying the loading of an object until we need this data. In other words, we load the object on demand, rather than unnecessarily loading data earlier.

I want to try using Lazy Loading in my simple console app.

**`Student` Class**

```
 public class Students
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string PESEL { get; set; }

        private Lazy<List<Students>> LazyStudents;
        

        public Students()
        {
           
        }

        public List<Students> StudentsProperty
        {
            get
            {
                if (LazyStudents == null)
                    LazyStudents = new Lazy<List<Students>>(() => LoadStudensList());
                return LazyStudents.Value;
            }
        }

        public List<Students> LoadStudensList()
        {
            List<Students> tempStudentsList = new List<Students>();
            tempStudentsList.Add(new Students() { Name = "Adam", Surname = "Wróbel", PESEL = "96120904999" });
            tempStudentsList.Add(new Students() { Name = "Edyta", Surname = "Urbańczyk", PESEL = "76354736458" });
            tempStudentsList.Add(new Students() { Name = "Gabriela", Surname = "Rydwańska", PESEL = "72637284923" });
            tempStudentsList.Add(new Students() { Name = "Dawid", Surname = "Rytel", PESEL = "62736482732" });

            return tempStudentsList;
        }
    }
```

**`Program` and `Main()` method:**

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Students students = new Students();
            
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            foreach (var items in students.StudentsProperty)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Imię: {items.Name}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Nazwisko: {items.Surname}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"PESEL: {items.PESEL}");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

I suppose that i use Lazy Loading, when i create new object of Students class StudentsProperty (return elements from Lazy List) still empty. Elements to LazyList will be added when i use method using StudentsProperty

```
 foreach (var items in students.StudentsProperty)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Imię: {items.Name}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Nazwisko: {items.Surname}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"PESEL: {items.PESEL}");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
            }
```

I Add breakpoint before `foreach` loop and i see that StudentsProperty has elements:
[image]

Have I implemented lazy loading incorrectly or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify this statement?: _"I suppose that i use Lazy Loading, when i create new object of Students class StudentsProperty (return elements from Lazy List) still empty"_

Comment: You are misusing the `Lazy<T>` class by deferring instantiation of it. It already handles the lazy aspect, but you are also doing that yourself by checking for null and instantiating it in `StudentsProperty`. You should instantiate the `Lazy<T>` at the field's point of declaration. As for why you can see the `StudentsProperty` property - the debugger is accessing it and so of course it gets instantiated, because the debugger is causing that!

Comment: You could probably go through some of the examples to understand the concept than understanding it just theoratically https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading

Comment: For starters, having `Lazy` means you no longer need any kind of `null` check -- just do `readonly Lazy<..> = new Lazy(...)`. Creating a `Lazy` lazily is superfluous. And second -- at the breakpoint, if you ask the debugger for `StudentsProperty` -- you're asking for the data, so of course it appears! Set a breakpoint only in `LoadStudensList` without inspecting expressions, step over `Main`, and see when it's called.

Comment: `Lazy<T>` is basically just a shortcut for `if (x == null) x = new List<T>()` . As others already noted, you can remove your null check.

Comment: The short answer your debugger is invoking the property and its loaded. If your property is not access it will not be invoked

Comment: you can not pretty much verify this behavior by debugging or any other way.. because as soon as you try to access the property to check if it has value, it gets populated by the Lazy loader, so you will never see it null

Comment: You may write a log entry in `LoadStudensList` method. So that you can verify if the log entry is generated only once because the method is supposed to be executed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lazy.Value` is when the lazy gets evaluated.

```
  LazyStudents = new Lazy<List<Students>>(() => LoadStudensList());
  return LazyStudents.Value;
```

doesn't make any sense. In the first line you say "evaluate when it's needed" and the second line says "I need it now".

By null checking you've did all the lazy evaluation on your own. Use either this:

```
    private Lazy<List<Students>> LazyStudents = new Lazy<List<Students>>(() => LoadStudensList());

    public List<Students> StudentsProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return LazyStudents.Value;
        }
    }
```

or this:

```
    private List<Students> LazyStudents;

    public List<Students> StudentsProperty
    {
        get
        {
            if (LazyStudents == null)
                LazyStudents = LoadStudensList();
            return LazyStudents;
        }
    }
```

They're supposed to be conceptually the same thing. Except multithreading safeguards, debugging and probably other pesky details, that make no difference **most** of the time.

The issue why you see values in debugger is bit more complicated. Looking at the [Lazy source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs), it **should** display null in debugger, thanks to `internal T ValueForDebugDisplay`. However, you're NOT looking at value of lazy. By looking at at `Students.StudentsProperty` you're looking at your `get` and debbuger evaluates getters and your getter forces Lazy to evaluate. You've bypassed all that debugging code that MS had created for us. Expose the `Lazy` directly, it's meant to be. Or, instead of debugger, put a log in `LoadStudensList()`

Bottom line: **`Lazy` is lazy only until `Value` gets called.**